# Applied for job with brother's competitor

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I am applying for a job at a recruitment consultant company, and my brother works for their direct competitor. The company is worried that this might bring conflict. I don't intend to speak with my brother about my job at all. We are both honest people.

How should I respond?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Why do they even know where your brother works?

Comment: Think the question is whether or not OP should apply due to a conflict of interest.

Comment: @zfrisch It's pretty common to have to declare potential conflicts of interest if you have family working for a competitor or a supplier.  In such cases, there may be times when you need to excuse yourself from decisions around the competitor or supplier.

Comment: @Eric Really? What the rest of my family do is not something I'd share - it's of no relevance and none of their business. The world is small - I know lots of people in lots of companies, they just need to deal with it.

Comment: @Dan You only need to share what the any member of the rest of the family does if it's something your company defines as either a competitor or supplier. But it's fairly common to have to disclose this and not doing so is grounds for disciplinary action (up to and including dismissal) in many places I've worked.

Comment: @SpaceDog Not disputing your experience, I've just never heard of this in the UK and I'd query the legality of it over here.

Comment: @Dan How would your company view you awarding contracts to your family member without them knowing it is your family member? The company I'm familiar with has offices in the UK and this reporting is required globally.

Answer (score 3):

I would respond, "We are all professionals. I can't imagine what you might think would cause a conflict."

Answer (score 1):

> The company is worried that this might bring conflict.

Companies generally don't worry about such conflicts, as they believe that professional life should be left back in the office.

But, you can respond like this:

> Both of us are professionals, and we don't talk about our professional
>   lives at home. So, I don't think that any conflict is going to arise
>   due to this issue.